# Visual Studio 08 Spell Check Addin?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, add-in

If possible one that supports at least spell checking:

- C# string literals
- HTML content
- Comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, 3 weeks later, I've stumbled across [CodeSpell](http://www.exactmagic.com/products/codespell/). *[**Note:** this link no longer works and the product does not appear to be listed by that company).*

Its $30 but has a trial period. Does everything I asked for. Check link to see features.

This [blog entry](http://www.indiegameguy.com/blogs/zman/archive/2005/11/30/visual-studio-2005-spell-checker.aspx), though dated, helped me out.

Edit: The original link is now invalid but this appears to be the [new home of CodeSpell at SubMain](http://submain.com/products/codespell.aspx). Here is acquisition [announcement from them](http://submain.com/blog/SubMainAcquiresExactMagicsTestMatrixCodeSpellAndStudioTools.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

The [plugin from Microsoft's Mikhail Arkhipov](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/29/spell-checker-update-2-2-full-support-for-vs-2008-sp1-simpler-setup-and-a-few-bug-fixes.aspx) does HTML and Comments, I don't believe it does C# strings, though.  I use the [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) plugin for [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for that.

Comment: I've had issues getting this to work in SP1. I'm not sure what the deal is but all the context menus are there and they seem to do nothing.

Comment: Note: Requires MS Office to be installed

Comment: Doesn't check C# strings!!! Only seems to check stuff that looks like HTML

Comment: Just kidding, the new version 2.2 does!!!! http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/29/spell-checker-update-2-2-full-support-for-vs-2008-sp1-simpler-setup-and-a-few-bug-fixes.aspx

Comment: @serhio, version 2.1 of that plugin supports VS 2005 SP1

Comment: there is update version for Visual Studio 2010
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0db4814c-255e-4cc6-a2c2-a428de7f8949/

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), there's a free addon for it called [Agent Smith Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/). One of its many features is a built in spell checker, that allows fixing the spelling mistakes using the ReSharper shortcut key, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I've installed this and next time I started Visual Studio and opened my Solution - VS hanged. So I uninstalled and now I'm testing out IntelliSpell http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/IntelliSpell/

Answer (score 3):

Visual Assist X.  Spell checks your comments and a whole lot more.

http://www.wholetomato.com/

Answer (score 1):

[FxCop ships with a spell check now](http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/06/08/fxcop-now-ships-with-the-spell-checker-libraries.aspx) - have you tried that?

[Here's a nice add-on](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/12/13/spell-checker-for-html-asp-net-jscript-vb-c-css-and-c-for-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx) for Visual Studio 2005/2008 by Mikhail Arkhipov of MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to check Comments and string spell checker. It's from component one http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/IntelliSpell/. It's very fast <strike>and there is a free community version.</strike>

Comment: This only has a free trial, otherwise $200 for a license.  A lot for spell check plugin.

Comment: There used to be a free community version but seems this no longer exists. Still a good product though and I think worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush also has spell check.

Comment: CodeRush can be found here - http://www.devexpress.com/coderush

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [Spelly](http://www.wndtabs.com/) is available, it would be pretty easy to update it for vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

[Spelly has been ported to VS 2003](http://www.wndtabs.com/). I don't know if it works with VS 2008 (because I'm very happy with Agent Smith for ReSharper), but source is included.

Answer (score -1):

I was running an obsolete version on Visual Studio 08, as of April last year this is the apparent update: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3d691d-8838-4d84-ad64-44a02db37e30/

Unfortunately for me, it only works on commented code and not strings.