# Is there a Visual Studio plugin that spellchecks strings and comments?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

Is there a Visual Studio plugin that spellchecks strings and comments?

**Duplicate** of [Visual Studio 08 Spell Check Addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947/visual-studio-08-spell-check-addin)

Comment: The word "Google" springs to mind...

Comment: Oh, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947/visual-studio-08-spell-check-addin

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I didn't see that one. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 08 Spell Check Addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947/visual-studio-08-spell-check-addin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look to [IntelliSpell](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/IntelliSpell/), a free version is available and it spell-check not only your xml comments, it checks even the strings in your code, resource files and more...

Answer (score 0):

I installed this and fits my needs. you can download it in here.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/86788d02-ce1e-4933-b499-cdba6a70f26f