# Spelling check in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, spell-checking

I read about [Spelling checker for VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947/visual-studio-08-spell-check-addin). I wonder if there is something similar for VS 2005 (+freeware, -shareware).

Thanks.

Comment: the thing i am against this spell check is because ,the variable names method names most of the cases wont belong to dictionary , so it has to be an intelligent dictionary which breaks down each word from the method name and then checks for spelling,which i dont think we can find such plug in.you can try from code project site to create a plug in yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a freeware.See if it comes in your budget:)

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/IntelliSpell/?gclid=CPOyrdDpyZ8CFYctpAodECFqUQ

http://www.componentsource.com/features/spelling/visual-studio-2005/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but this board has a direct download and also mentions another option that looks good.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130604100051/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ajames/archive/2008/01/04/spell-check-add-on-for-visual-studio-20052008.aspx)